# Python: Moviepy makes images much lighter

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

When I try to generate a simple video compiling one image and a specified audio clip, the image becomes much lighter than the original. With an audio file `audio.wav` and and image file `image.png` which looks as follows:

[image]

With the following code:

```
import os
if '/' in __file__:
    slash = '/'
else:
    slash = '\\'

import sys

os.chdir(slash.join(__file__.split(slash)[:-1]))


from moviepy.editor import *

FPS = 25

def create_video(audio, image):
    square = ImageClip(image)

    audio = AudioFileClip(audio)

    dur = audio.duration
    square.duration = dur

    ## When I originally posted the question I had the following two lines
    #square.set_audio(audio)
    #square.audio = audio

    ## A more elegant way to do the same thing (the problem still remains):
    square = square.set_audio(audio)
    ## The line "square.set_audio(audio)" does nothing, as tburrows13 commented

    return square

audio = 'audio.wav'
image = 'image.png'

result = create_video(audio, image)

result.write_videofile('video.mp4', fps=FPS)#, codec='mpeg4') # Many options...
```

the image in the resulting video file looks as follows:

[image]

As we can see, the grey is much lighter and the blue is much lighter. Can anyone tell what's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but the line `square.set_audio(audio)` does nothing, as it returns a copy of `square` with the audio set to `audio`. If you do `square = square.set_audio(audio)`  then you shouldn't need the next line.

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right. Moviepy has proven to be a library with full of surprising difficulties, and I've often settled to the first solution that has worked, even if isn't very elegant. I made the change to my script, the same colour distortion/whitening problem still exists (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've managed to solve it myself. The image needs to be in jpg format, png images will be made lighter.

I converted the image to jpg, here's a screenshot of the new video:

[image: screenshot]

By the way, it is also important that the width and height of the images (in pixels) are even numbers. Otherwise media players might not show the image even though YouTube seems to accept them.